# "Write Error" plot R

Tags: r

Every time I try to plot anything, such as:

```
C1<-c(1,0,0,1)
plot(C1)
```

where C1 is any generic vector, I get the following error pop-up:

R error
Write Error.

I tried refreshing R to no avail. How do I fix this?

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

120 attached packages

Comment: Please provide `C1`

Comment: It's really any generic list or vector. I get the same error no matter what function I use that involves plotting, from pheatmap to plot

Comment: Try "clear all plots"

Comment: I did dev.off(), it didn't help, in fact it gives me the same error message lol

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It is at least possible that your version of R has become corrupt somehow.

Comment: RStudio? Rterm? Rscript? Emacs/ESS? RTVS? It might help to provide output from `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()`.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: It's RStudio. Running a script in RStudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the server, not R. Thanks for the help everyone!